# GUI on ubuntu server 17.10 problem

Tags: server, password, gui, 17.10, lock

I installed ubuntu server 17.10 on my workstation. It worked correctly. When I added a GUI (sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop) and rebooted the computer, I have no way to login as user because the password is neither accepted in GUI nor in terminal (after ctrl+alt+Fn). My keyboard was verified and is the correct one. Is there any way to solve this issue?
Regards

Comment: What is the error in TTY, exactly?

Comment: It says wrong password. Fortunately I have resolved the problem by deleting .Xauthority and .ICEauthority files.  Thanks for your feed.

Answer (score 0):

Tarek,
Can you explain how you deleted the .Xauthority and .ICEauthority files.
I am having the same problem.

Siv

Comment: Try to boot your machine on Live DVD (use try ubuntu) then move to the home directory of you installed machine.